# Powerpivot refresh Error

Tags: powerpivot, data-refresh

The data refresh is working fine in my test environment ,But in production it is a new server and i had created a tabular model and roles and deployed to same share point ,When i try to refresh within the browser ,i am getting the below error but if i download to local desktop and refresh it works fine ,the roles also works fine,at the same time if i schedule a data refresh ,this also works fine,I am not sure why it is not working when opening in browser

> 'An error occurred during an attempt to establish a connection to the
>   external data source. The following connections failed to refresh:'

[image: Error]